How do you use specific coordinates or ratios to perform a Cloudinary Crop transformation?
I am creating a social media site. In this site is a page to upload your profile picture. Then, I use an absolute positioned div that the user can move around and basically "tag" their photo. So, I have the Left and Top, or even X and Y ratios for where they are located on the image... I set up my backend to upload the image to Cloudinary, but now when I need to access the image URL and send it back to the client, I want to perform the transformations. Chat GPT put me on c_crop with w,h, but it keeps telling me to use "g_custom:x_0.5,y_0.5" or something similar to position it. I tried to go to the Cloudinary documentation, but it's all about auto gravity and mentions g_custom once, but it didn't give any other information... I have no idea if I just missed something or what but please help.
Here are some URLs I have tried that that Chat GPT recommended..
https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/g_custom:0.5:0.5,c_crop,h_300,w_300/sample.jpg
(didn't work at all)
https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/g_custom:face,c_crop,h_300,w_300/sample.jpg
(works, but... it doesn't allow me to use my ratios!)
https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/c_crop,g_custom,x_0.2,y_0.3,w_0.5,h_0.5/sample.jpg
(works, but... changing x or y does absolutely nothing!)
Notice how changing the x and y doesn't help with the focus of the crop.
(by the way I literally learned Cloudinary today so, I am still unsure of the gravity terminology, I believe it is just the 'focus' or center of the crop...)
Thanks guys!

g_custom requests that the cropping uses coordinates were already added to the asset's metadata via the API or UI: https://cloudinary.com/documentation/resizing_and_cropping#fixed_coordinates_cropping
To manually select x/y coordinates in the URL, you can omit the g parameter entirely and then add your x/y values and width and height: https://cloudinary.com/documentation/resizing_and_cropping#fixed_coordinates_cropping
Example: https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/c_crop,x_0.2,y_0.3,w_0.5,h_0.5/sample.jpg
